# Phone number textbox auto focus to next text box after entering in first textbox in android app

Tags: android, hybrid-mobile-app

How text box automatically move (auto focus) to next control when limit is reached in android app.
basically i have hybrid application (developed in ASP.net). which renders on android app.
it's works in browser but doesn't work in mobile app.

Can any body can provide solution to this.

Comment: Do you have several `edittexts`? You could check the amount of letters entered in `onTextChanged` event and when it reaches desired limit call `requestFocus` on next view

Comment: Yes. as I said it is hybrid application developed in asp.net which renders on Android container.  so those text are on web pages. jquery script written for that but that is not working on mobile app.

Comment: have you tried what I suggested?

Comment: No. i am just thinking how do I access those textboxes which are there on web page.